# Get 500 Error in Laravel with SQL Server database in long results

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, wamp

I connect to SQL Server in laravel using PDO (in Wamp Server).

Normally I have no problem, but when the number of rows of results increases (more than 50,000 rows) and I also use Left Join, I get 500 error or a blank white page.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the 500 error, is it possible that you are running out of memory?

Comment: Most of the times 500 internal server error details are captured in /storage/logs/laravel.log, please have a look at that. Also, in such cases of very big number of rows, we use server side pagination feature of Laravel- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a timeout issue on processing the request (check the PHP error log to confirm this hypothesis).
By default there is this setting in php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
```

If processing takes more than `max_execution_time` value (in seconds), the script ends with fatal error.
If you are not in safe mode, you can change this value on runtime, only for single script, by:
`set_time_limit ( int $seconds )`

[See PHP manual for details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. Not able to check **laravel** error page.

then I got solution.

Check .env file
**APP_DEBUG=false**

I have changed it to **true**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was getting 500 error without description in debugging mode.